# Jain-sip tcp socket is not clossed even after multiple retransmission on cent os

Tags: centos, jain-sip

I am using jain-sip stack on centos 64bit machine, and below is the detail steps and explanation of the issue

- Register to SIP Server using jain-sip client
- Register timeouts for every 360 seconds
- During Reregistration process if server is down due to network issue, the outbound TCP socket is
  continue to retransmit the registration request, it takes around 15 minutes to close this socket

So client is unable to register for 15 minutes even after loosing network connectivity for few seconds

This works fine with the same code on windows, in windows there will be 5 retransmission then socket gets closed, when client re tries new socket will be opened.

Please help to resolve this issue on centos

Comment: Can you attach DEBUG logs? Is this BIO or NIO?

Comment: it is NIO, will try to attach the logs soon

Comment: Also which version of jain-sip do you use?

Comment: We are using jain-sip-api-1.2.jar and jain-sip-ri-1.2.165.jar

Comment: Try this jsip https://jsip.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jsip/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/jain-sip-1.2.2311.tar.gz

Comment: same behaviour using above artifact as well. 

From the "netstat" command i can see that send-Q has around 663 bytes of data pending

Comment: If the socket is still online and the send q is nonempty it is resposibility of the TCP stack to deliver the bytes in the queue with TCP retransmissions. Have you tweaked these options? When the socket gets closed who initiates the FIN/RST?

Answer (score 0):

If the socket is in frozen state then the OS should take care of the recovery. Monitor with tcpdump what happens with TCP retransmissions. If you want to force JSIP to close the socket, use `((SIPTransactionStack)sipStack).closeAllSockets();` and then implement your recovery logic in the app.

Comment: This solution helped me. Thank you Vladimir Ralev